# Moved WordPress and changed image links but they aren't working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, blogs

I've moved my WP installation and updated the URL from www.scotthelme.co.uk/blog to www.scotthelme.co.uk, this all went fine. The blog loads at the correct (new) address but the images do not. I ran a SQL statement against the db to change all the references which worked as you can see on the page, but they still don't work. Any suggestions?

```
 UPDATE wp_posts set post_content=REPLACE(post_content, 'www.scotthelme.co.uk/blog/', 'www.scotthelme.co.uk/');
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML?  Did you verify the `<img>` tags point to a valid source, and the images are actually at that location?

Comment: Yeah you can see on the page they point to the right place, opening the link in a new tab shows the image. Cleared cache to ensure it isn't a local thing. Still no joy.

Comment: There is probably a `<a href="fullimage.jpg"><img src="smallimg.jpg" /></a>` - Maybe the hyperlinks were updated but the `<img>` tags were not?  Which is why I'd like you to post the *actual* HTML from the page.

Comment: I was going to suggest that the permissions on your /uploads folder were not correct since I was getting a lot of permission denied errors, however it looks like your problem has been solved.

Comment: I think I cracked it, the image hotlink prevention in the .htaccess hadn't updated for some reason. Update that and it now seems to be working as intended! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cracked it, the image hotlink prevention in the .htaccess hadn't updated for some reason. Updated that and it now seems to be working as intended!